# Control a 12 v circuit using wall plug 220v ac timer

Tags: ac, timer

I want to use a standard supermarket 220v ac timer to switch a 12-volt circuit. I was thinking about letting the timer run on the outlet, and just desolder the relay separating it from the ac, keeping the 24 v line needed to drive the relay and hooking my 12 v line on the switch contacts. Is it a good idea?

Comment: Never a good idea to hack mains equipment unless you know exactly what you are doing. Why not just plug a 12V wall wart into the timer outlet - switched 12V source, no chance of winning a Darwin award.

Comment: I have some mains equipment experience, it's the little dc that is killing me. 12v timers are expensive, and don't work well for my purpose because of relatively high amps

Answer (score 2):

I think I would just get another relay. One where the coil is rated for 220VAC, and the switch is rated for at least 12VDC, and at least however many Amps you intend to run through it. Some relays may not have a DC rating. Make sure you get one that does.

Comment: I was going to keep the timer circuit as a whole, just swap the switched wire for 12v instead of 220v.the relay is 24vdc,and is a monopole switch,powered directly from the board. I was going to keep that for keeping the mod as simple as possible, because electronic parts are really hard to come by in my location.

Comment: Might help if you added a schematic or other type of diagram to your question. It is hard to follow what you propose to do. If I understand correctly, it will probably work, but the timer will not have any DC rating. Relays not designed for DC may fail after a short time.

Comment: The schematic of the darn thing is impossible to find so i will try to be as explicit as possible. The temporized socket has 2 separated circuits inside. One for the programable timer wich runs off a 1,2v nimh battery, and the other wich has a rectifying bridge to run the relay and charge the battery. The relay is a monoswitch wich cuts the hot 220v wire. My ideea was to desolder the 220ac line from the relay intreruptor and replace it with my 12vdc line while keeping the rest of circuitry intact.

Comment: It will probably work. But could create a shock hazard (if 220 somehow accidentally connects to what is supposed to be 12V) and may fail prematurely due to arcing during contact bounce. Where is the 12V coming from and how much current will be flowing through the relay? Add that information to your question.

Comment: 12v comes from a separate 5A rated led driver. Current trough relay will be around 3,5A. To avoid 220v somehow comming from the circuit, I taught about desoldering the relay from the board, as I have no schematic, and adding extension wires to get the 24 v for the relay from the board, that way there are none hidden paths for high current to get in. The relay can switch 2000w at 220vac.

Comment: Can you not just plug the LED driver into the timer outlet? As Jim Dearden suggested? Also, does the relay have a DC current rating on it? The issue is that DC switching produces more arcing when the relay contacts bounce (every time the relay closes the circuit). DC relays are designed to deal with this arcing, one way or another. If the relay does not have a DC current rating, it is not advisable to use it to switch DC current. The relay may fail after a much shorter time than you expect.

Comment: Yes it does. 15vdc to be precise

Comment: What about current?

Comment: 15vdc 6 ampers as read from the relay

Comment: Seems promising. What you want to do, it is totally a hack, but it seems like it will work. I still would prefer to power the 12V supply from the 220V timer. Not sure why you can't do that.

Comment: Because the timed relay disconnects only part of the circuit, the other part has to have power

Comment: I was wrong. The relay is rated 220vca 15A,125vca 15A,28vdc 15A,14vdc 10A.Anyways, did the hack this morning, now waiting for silicone to dry, woll return with the results later. Thank you all for your assistance .

Comment: Hack worked like a charm. I flipped the relay upside down, reglued it to the board, added 2 wires to get the 24vdc for the relay, and soldered my 12 vdc to the switch. Done some testing, it works, has some delay due to large surge protection caps wich i did not remove.